# Smallest Circle that encircles $4$ circles

Tags: circles, packing-problem

I want to calculate the radius of the smallest circle (radius $R$) that can hold $4$ circles (with radii $a, b, c, d$) inside it, such that:

1. No circles overlaps one other.
2. $a \ge b \ge c \ge d.$

*Radius of $a, b, c, d$ are known to us.*

*We need to find $R$.*

***In this problem, the radius of $a,b,c,d$ are not always same.***

I'm curious to find the solution for the following cases:

Case 1: $a = b = c = d$

Case 2: $a = b = c > d$

Case 3: $a = b > c \ge d$

Case 4: $a > b \ge c \ge d$

Comment: There are a lot of cases, and in the last case, at least, the answer is going to be a non-trivial function of three dimensionless variables.  Is there some more specific question you really care about, or are you actually just curious?

Comment: @mjqxxxx~~ A simple Question: Possible/not?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/pcmi/hstp/resources/circlepacking/paper.html might help, although it is not exactly what you want. Case 1 is also a well known question you can read about here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html

Answer (score 0):

It is simple if $d$ is small enough.  You can use [Decartes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) to find the radius $r$ outside the $a,b,c$ circles as $(\frac 1a + \frac 1b + \frac 1c-\frac 1r)^2=2(\frac 1{a^2}+\frac 1{b^2}+\frac 1{c^2}+\frac 1{r^2})$ because the $d$ circle fits in one of the small spaces left over.

Comment: ~ Thanks for the solution. But I think Decartes' Theorem solves for one particular case in this problem. What if d does not fit into the space and contributes to increase R. There should be some XYZ123 theorem for that.  Also, we need to find out for what threshold d, Decartes' theorem is applicable, or otherwise XYZ123 theorem.

Comment: @KishoreDebnath:  I don't know any simple formula in that case, which is why I didn't supply it.